# Pinescript - 3 levels of confirmed conditions with time space between?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to work out how to write an indicator that would be valid only if a condition is met and then if another condition is met after (within a timeframe limit) and another too after this second one. It is related to trend change analysis with 2 confirmations :

- Condition 1 appears
  -> Test 1 OK, move to await condition 2
  -> Test NOK, wait for condition to appear
- Condition 2 appears AND condition 1 was OK within 5 bars of condition 2 appearance 
  -> Test 2 OK, move to await condition 3
  -> Test NOK, wait for condition to appear within the timeframe of 5 bars. If not, come back to await condition 1
- Condition 3 appears AND condition 2 was OK within 5 bars of condition 3 appearance 
  -> Test 3 OK, green light to place order at market price
  -> Test NOK, wait for condition to appear within the timeframe of 5 bars. If not, come back to await condition 2 or if timeframe exceeded too, come back to await condition 1

How would you write the structure of the code? Do I need to use nested if / for?
Is is possible with pine script?

Thanks

EDIT :
I'm merging the 2 scritps you provided but I don't understand why my barssince / bar_index logic don't work?

(CondB OK if bar index is between bar condA and condA + 5)

```
//@version=4
//@author=LucF, for PineCoders
study("AB or BA", "", true)

// ————— Trigger conditions.
WMA1  = wma(close, 20)
WMA2 = wma(close, 50)
WMA3  = wma(close, 100)
WMA4  = wma(close, 200)

condATrigger = crossover(WMA1,WMA3)
condBTrigger = crossover(WMA2,WMA3)

condA = false
condB = false

var LastCondWasA = false

if condATrigger and not LastCondWasA
    condA := true
    LastCondWasA := true
else
    if condBTrigger and LastCondWasA and (barssince(condA) < bar_index) and (bar_index <= barssince(condA) + 5)
        condB := true
        LastCondWasA := false
    else
        condB := false

plotchar(condA, "condA", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, 30, size = size.tiny, text = "A")
plotchar(condB, "condB", "▼", location.abovebar, color.red, 30, size = size.tiny, text = "B")
```